# ToolbarAndroid not rendering

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use **ToolbarAndroid** on my React Native Project.

But the Toolbar is not being rendered. Am I missing anything?

Here's the snippet:

**toolbar.js**

```
import React, {
    Component
} from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    ToolbarAndroid,
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

export default class Toolbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Icon.ToolbarAndroid
                title = {this.props.title}
                titleColor = 'black'
                navIconName = "android-menu"
                style = {styles.toolbar}
            />
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    toolbar: {
        backgroundColor: 'firebrick',
        height: 56
    }
});
```

I've then imported this file to my main file where the component gets rendered.

**UPDATE**

I applied **width** to the **toolbar** and now it's showing. But why should we have to use **width** and what's the appropriate value to make the **toolbar** render along whole screen ?

Is it a bug ?

**Updated style**

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    toolbar: {
        backgroundColor: 'firebrick',
        height: 56,
        width: 300
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a working example of such component (but not the same):

```
<ToolbarAndroid
  title = {this.props.title}
  titleColor = 'black'
  navIconName = "android-menu"
>
  <View style={styles.toolbar}>
    <Text>{this.props.title}</Text>
  </View>
</ToolbarAndroid>
```

You have to pass a child view to ToolbarAndroid. Also using color names like `firebase` is not supported out of the box.